# I have a problem with my php script

Tags: php, server-configuration

I have a form where it request name,email,zipcode. However the problem is that. when you click on submit. it ask you to open the file it doesn't go to the script.

The website is http://childcarelv.org/newsletter.html

Comment: What about posting the code?

Comment: Is your server properly configured to serve `.php` pages?

Comment: @John http://childcarelv.org/newsletter.html

Comment: Take the "h" off the beginning of the URL and it works.

Answer (score 12):

PHP isn't being handled by your server.  Instead, it is just being output straight to the browser.

This is a server configuration issue.

Your server is configured with the correct MIME type (it is returning application/x-httpd-php), but isn't set up to actually use PHP to process it.

Since you are using Apache, read the configuration instructions here:  http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.unix.apache2.php

Looks like you might be hosting with ipower.com.  If that is the case, this is an issue for them to solve.

Comment: @adlan, If you are paying a web host for hosting services, you need to contact them.  It is a problem with their server configuration.  If you are hosting this yourself, read the directions on the link I posted for instructions.

Answer (score 0):

From your description it seems that server is not able to execute the php script, and thus gives it as download to the client.

You should try to put the following code in a file named testphp.php and place in your public home directory and go to the page to see if php extension is mapped to the php module on your server.

```
<?

phpinfo();

?>
```

This is just to verify/prove that there is nothing wrong in your script, and even a simple test script won't work.

Comment: If the server cannot handle PHP how do you want to execute `phpinfo()`  by accessing `testphp.php` (from the browser)?

Comment: Well I did what you said I created testphp.php. and I opened it

Comment: @felix - What i suggested was just to prove that there is nothing wrong in his script, and even the simple test php won't work. @adlan Now i see that the testphp.php is opening up fine, this means php is working fine on your server. Now your script should also work. Let me know if it still doesn't